# return a specific datafrom wcf

Tags: c#, wcf

my method look like this:

```
public List<CivarTransporteService.Model.Cliente> getClientes()
    {
        using (CivarTransporteService.Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer context = new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
        {
            return context.Cliente.ToList();

        }
    }
```

and my cs:

```
public interface ICatalogsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<CivarTransporteService.Model.Cliente> getClientes();
}
```

actually getClientes return all the fields of Clientes database but i just need the name of the client
 how could i do this? thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method to get only the Name column. you need to update your method signature to return a list of string now.

Assuming `Name` is a property of the Client entity

```
public List<string> getClientes()
{
   using (var context = new Model.CivarTransporteModelContainer())
   {
       return context.Cliente.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList();    
   }
}
```

And the interface signature as well

```
public interface ICatalogsService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<string> getClientes();
}
```

**Or** if you do not want to update the existing interface and it's implementation, you can do this at whererever you are calling it.

```
ICatalogsService catalogService;
catalogService = new SomeConcreteCatalogService(); // not the best to "new" it up. 
                                               // But that is not the real question here.
var clientNameList = catalogService.getClients().Select(s=>s.Name).ToList();
```

Comment: Thx you so much it is what i was looking for, i am just getting an error when converting to list

Comment: Cannot implicity convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<civartransporteService.Model.Cliente>

Comment: Are you assigning the result to a`List<Cliente>` ? with the above change(**1st** solution), Your method returns a list of string, not list of Cliente. So change the type of the variable to which you assign it. You may simply use `var someList=catalogService.getClients();`

Comment: @jm167 If this solution worked for you please mark it as the answer, and upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand a little upon @Shyju's answer in case you're interested in more than just 1 field.  I did a similar thing when returning database objects over WCF Data Service.  I didn't want the entire database model being returned, just a subset of data, so I created an public version of the class:

```
[DataContract]
public class PublicCliente
{
    [DataMember(Order = 1)]
    public int Id;

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string Name;

    public PublicCliente(Cliente c)
    {
        Id = c.Id;
        Name = c.Name;
    }
}
```

Then in the data service method, I did this:

```
return context.Cliente.Select(
        c => new PublicCliente(c)).ToList();
```